# Is it possible to manually add different PairPlots (returning PairGrids) in the same figure?

Tags: python, layout, charts, seaborn

I have the following code to generate 3 `PairPlots`, each one with a single ax:

```python
sns.pairplot(df, x_vars="Agricultural area", y_vars="Wooded area", hue="Elevation")
sns.pairplot(df, x_vars="Agricultural area", y_vars="Settlement area", hue="Elevation")
sns.pairplot(df, x_vars="Agricultural area", y_vars="Unproductive area", hue="Elevation")

plt.show()
```

This works, but it generates 3 distinct figures. I now would like to have the result in the same figure, for example using this:

```
fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 3, sharey=True, figsize=(15, 10))
```

Then adding `PairGrid[0],[0]` to the first ax (`axes[0]`) and so on. There is no `ax` parameter in `pairplot` which I guess is normal as it returns a grid, not an ax. Is this possible (how)? Else is there a better solution to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Got it:

```python
sns.pairplot(
    df,
    x_vars=["Wooded area", "Settlement area", "Unproductive area"],
    y_vars="Agricultural area",
    hue="Elevation",
)
```